# After a branch has been merged into another, is there a commit created on it?

Tags: git

What is the relation between the following two branches `A01234` and `staging`?

1. Does the following command imply that after the branch `A01234` was
   merged into the branch `staging`, there was a new commit created on
   the branch `A01234`, which hasn't been merged into the branch
   `staging`?

   ```
   $ git log
   commit 56eca45
   Author: tom@example.com <tom@example.com>
   Date:   Tue Mar 14 17:12:53 2017 -0400

       A01234: Fixed some other problems

   commit f458a8d
   Merge: 5e5da5a 69e489f
   Author: tom@example.com <tom@example.com>
   Date:   Tue Mar 14 15:27:35 2017 -0400

       A01234: Merge with staging; Fixed some problems
   ```
2. Does the following command imply that the latest commit on the
   branch `A01234` has been merged into the branch `staging`?

   ```
   $ git branch --contains A01234
   * A01234
     staging
   ```

What might be the reason that I have these two "contrary" outputs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No. The `git log` output that you provided doesn't provide any information about when point `A01234` was merged into `staging`  — but the `git branch` information shows that it was indeed merged into staging *after* its last commit. The second-to-last log entry you see is (presumably, judging from the message, since we can't look at the referenced SHAs) a merge of `staging` into `A01234` to resolve conflicts prior to merging the other way.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean there are two merges, with the first one being "a merge of staging into A01234 to resolve conflicts" and the second one being "merging the other way"? Why do we need the two merges?

Comment: @Tim: the `git log` output shows only *one* merge, not *two* merges. Because you've shown two separate outputs, and not used `git log --graph --decorate`, and not shown various other things, everything else is just guessing.